# javascript with improper initiation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

As my homework I have to prepare an asp webpage for database frontpage. To gain some extra points we can add a javascript. I deceided to add a clock I've found somewhere in script tutorials and modified it a little, but my skills are not enough to place it correctly

I want to place it in my MasterPage, but whole page dissapears only the clock lefts if I add it like this:

```
<div id="Zawartosc" onload="showTheTime();">
   <%--  clock --%>
   <script src="Script.js"></script>    
</div>
```

and here is the clock script:

```
function showTheTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    var ampm = "am";
    var colon = '<IMG SRC="clock/colon.gif">';

    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    else hours = hours + '';

    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    else minutes = minutes + '';

    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    else seconds = seconds + '';

    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + hours.charAt(0) + '.gif">');
    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + hours.charAt(1) + '.gif">');
    document.write(colon);
    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + minutes.charAt(0) + '.gif">');
    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + minutes.charAt(1) + '.gif">');
    document.write(colon);
    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + seconds.charAt(0) + '.gif">');
    document.write('<IMG SRC="clock/' + seconds.charAt(1) + '.gif">');
}
setTimeout("showTheTime()", 1000);
showTheTime();
```

could you please lead or help me to correct code and make the clock appear correctly with my page?

Comment: How did you added it to your master page?

Comment: only with id="Zawartosc" described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
    <div id="Zawartosc" onload="showTheTime();">

        <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </div>


function createElementImg(source) {
    var img =  document.createElement('img');
    img.src = source;
    return img;
}
function showTheTime() {
    var clockEle =  document.getElementById("Zawartosc");
    while (clockEle.hasChildNodes()) {
        clockEle.removeChild(clockEle.lastChild);
    }
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    var ampm = "am";
    var colon = "clock/colon.gif";

    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    else hours = hours + '';

    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    else minutes = minutes + '';

    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    else seconds = seconds + '';

    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + hours.charAt(0) + '.gif"));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + hours.charAt(1) + '.gif"));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg(colon));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + minutes.charAt(0) + '.gif"));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + minutes.charAt(1) + '.gif"));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg(colon));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + seconds.charAt(0) + '.gif"));
    clockEle.appendChild(createElementImg("clock/' + seconds.charAt(1) + '.gif"));
}
setTimeout("showTheTime()", 1000);
showTheTime();
```

Comment: Needed only to repair the gif's shortcuts by replacing ' with " in createElementImg("clock/' + hours.charAt(0) + '.gif"). ONE MORE THING TO DO: make the script running with the interval... clock will update when setTimeout("showTheTime()", 1000); will be in function area...

Answer (score 3):

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an
>   HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Comment: @mallorm: have a dummy, empty div, find it with getElementById and then set its innerHTML to what you need.